# Example of $M \subset \mathcal{C}_0 $ where $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{f \in M} w_{\delta}(f) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $\mathcal{C}_0 := \{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ continuous}, f(0) = 0\}$. I'm looking for an example of a subset $M \subset \mathcal{C}_0 $ with

$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{f \in M} w_{\delta}(f) > 0 $$

where

$$w_{\delta}(f) := \sup \{|f(s) - f(t)|: s,t \in [0,1], |s-t| \le \delta\}$$ It holds that $\forall f \in \mathcal{C}_0:  \lim_{\delta \to 0}w_{\delta}(f) = 0$.

Comment: Why not just $M$ being the whole space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=x^n$.   For $\delta \in (0, 1)$,  notice that
$$
  \omega _\delta (f_n) \geq  f(1) - f(1-\delta ) = 1-(1-\delta )^n.
  $$

Setting $M=\{f_n:n\in {\mathbb N}\}$,  it follows that
$$
  \sup_{f \in M} w_{\delta}(f) \geq 
  \sup_{n\in {\mathbb N}} 1-(1-\delta )^n = 1,
  $$
and therefore
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sup_{f \in M} w_{\delta}(f) = 1. $$

Comment: Do I see it correctly, that $M$ is also not precompact?

Comment: Yes, I believe your condition is incompatible with equi-continuity, which in turn is related to compactness via Arzela-Ascoli.